# Consumer.Committed returning null OffsetMetaData

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Kafka Consumer API Committed returns null offset. Not sure what is wrong.

```
val partitions = new util.HashSet[TopicPartition]

for (partitionInfo <- consumer.partitionsFor(topic)) {
  partitions.add(new TopicPartition(partitionInfo.topic, partitionInfo.partition))
}

consumer.assign(partitions)

val latestOffset= consumer.committed(partitions)

println ("LatestOffset Object "+ latestOffset)

val map = latestOffset.map{ case(t, o) => t.partition() -> o.offset()}
```

output of print:

```
{partition-1=null, partition-0=null}
```

End result i want to get a map of partition->offset like `{"0"->200,"1"->100}`

Why LatestOffset Object Offset metadata shows null? If I use consumer.position it works.

Using kafka client   :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is showing `null` because your consumer never consumed and therefore never committed any offsets.

Have your consumer consuming messages from the assigned topic, commit them and then some values will show up from the `committed` method.

Comment: The Consumer group does commit and it shows up as part of position as well.

Comment: Does that mean if its a new consumer group , the committed will return null ? Can we put any default to return some offsets?

Comment: How ever an old consumer group which has already committed lot of events. returns Null. Anything you observe wrong in my code. I am clueless. Position works every time. Committed does not work .

Comment: It's really bad practice for the Kafka client to return a null object like that. Modern code avoids designing apis that can occasionally generate null objects.